Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop
So this is my first time with Playwright so I thought to try out the examples only to find none of the work and the errors dont make sense:
I have tried all the examples in the docs and on the github pages and keep getting errors that I simply dont understand.
CODE:
`

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

playwright = sync_playwright().start()

browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
page = browser.new_page()
page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")
page.screenshot(path="example.png")
browser.close()

playwright.stop()

`
**ERROR:
**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 3
      1 from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
----> 3 playwright = sync_playwright().start()
      5 browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
      6 page = browser.new_page()

File ~/Downloads/Packaging Industry Anomaly DEtection (PIADE)/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_context_manager.py:84, in PlaywrightContextManager.start(self)
     83 def start(self) -> SyncPlaywright:
---> 84     return self.__enter__()

File ~/Downloads/Packaging Industry Anomaly DEtection (PIADE)/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_context_manager.py:47, in PlaywrightContextManager.__enter__(self)
     45             self._own_loop = True
     46         if self._loop.is_running():
---> 47             raise Error(
     48                 """It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
     49 Please use the Async API instead."""
     50             )
     52         # Create a new fiber for the protocol dispatcher. It will be pumping events
     53         # until the end of times. We will pass control to that fiber every time we
     54         # block while waiting for a response.
     55         def greenlet_main() -> None:

Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
Please use the Async API instead.


I assume you're running this code in a notebook kernel. This is not possible to use the sync API in this context since there is a running asyncio eventloop.
Use the async API or run your code outside of a notebook kernel.
